# Access internal objects from ASPx Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several internals object in an API.
I can access them from the code behind but I can't access them from the asp page like :

`<% API.InternalObject.Method %>`

Is there a way to set the namespace like `namespace project {}` but for the ASPx file ?

Comment: Change them to public or *don't* try to access them at all. `internal` means `I don't want people to call them from their own assemblies`

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I have a website and only it can access this API.

Comment: What is exactly what you want? If *you* specified `internal` you need to change it to public. After all, a web site isn't a library that can be used by other code.

Comment: I have a WebSite and I have an API (an other project). I want the website to use this API. It works from code behind but not if I write code directly in the ASPX file.

Comment: instead of repeating the question, read the comments. Either make them public or don't use them. *Why* did you use `internal` if you intended to use the objects? `internal` isn't a licensing mechanism

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I want to prevent the use of my APIs outside my projects.

Comment: It's also a very bad idea to use library objects in the views and pages. Views and pages should *not* contain business logic, only display logic and the model objects needed to render what they need. Not the *data layer* entities either since they need transformations before they can be displayed on a page

Comment: You won't be able to do it this way. It's not what you asked either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Other.Assembly")]` attribute.

But I would first think if you really need it.

I've used it in the past to make it possible to test internal classes in my test projects.

Comment: I already use it to make this API visible to this project. That is why it is visible from code behind. I want to use this API from ASPX file